# How can I create a value from two other values in the same table in my SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named "orders" in an SQL database:

```
id  date   name  orderID
========================
1   1502   John    ?
2   1502   Jane    ?
```

The "id" is set to AUTO_INCREMENT and the "date" is created when I insert data via my php form:

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $valid = true;


        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (name,date) values(?,CURDATE())";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($name));
            Database::disconnect();
        }
}
```

I wish that the value for "orderID" is created automatically from the values "id" and "date":

```
id  date   name  orderID
========================
1   1502   John    15021
2   1502   Jane    15022
```

Comment: [`SELECT CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: Why bother, You have the `id` and the `date` when you want to put an `orderID` on a document or the screen just concatanate those 2 value at that point.

Comment: Use a `view`... why store it when you can save space. Create a view and put the OrderID at end with concatenation of Date+ID.

Comment: Thank you, what is a `view`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact, that the id is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` you have no hand on this value. But it's quite simple. Add a `AFTER INSERT` trigger to the table and let it update the `orderID` column afterwards.

Here a quick example of a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourTrigger
AFTER INSERT
   ON yourTable FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    UPDATE yourTable
    SET orderid = CAST(date as char(4)) + CAST(id as char(1))
    WHERE ID = NEW.id

END;
```

Comment: Hello, I added the after Insert trigger into my SQL but now my script is not working anymore. I get the error: **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'orders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.** I think my database is broken now.

Comment: I wish to delete this trigger from my database. How is this possible?

Comment: Yes, just use this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html. But by the way, if you get this error you have created the trigger wrong. You should provide the code.

Comment: I tried to do it but I get a new error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[IF EXISTS] [orders.]orders' at line 1

Comment: Well, as already stated in your error message, you have a synthax error. Without your code you try to execute no one can help you. I'm quite sure you just copied something and haven't changed it the correct way?

Comment: Oh no :( Does it help if I delete my database table and start all over again?

Comment: Well you can start it again. But why don't you just show how you try to delete the trigger? I bet you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: I do not know how to show you. I inserted some code into the SQL tab of mySQL, and I do not remember exactly, something like: `CREATE TRIGGER orders 
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO orders (orderID)
  VALUES ('id');`Is there a way to see the code?

Comment: To delete it I wrote in the SQL tab: DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] [orders]orders

Comment: Try: `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS orders`
Do you named your trigger really orders or is it just the name of the table?
You have forgotten to remove the [] from the example which marks `IF EXISTS` as optional value.

Comment: Oh great, it works again! Sorry, I am not advanced enough in mySQL for this operation :) But thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Well no problem @Jarla. :-) Hope this will work for you. I've added you a example for a trigger in my original answer.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to write this trigger code also into my code I added above?

Comment: Well your code above provoked the error you have. Because you have a cyclic dependency in your code. Your code says: If a row is inserted in orders, then insert a row into orders - which will cause the trigger to fire again and again and again........ Until the error pops up. You get it? :-)

Comment: Well no, the trigger is just on the DBMS side. The idea with `MAX()` which is posted here is also not the best way to get it. Maybe it could work if you integrate `LAST_INSERT_ID + 1` into your `VALUES` part as a subquery for example.

Comment: One last question. When I add your code into the SQL tab. How is it later possible to see if the table has a trigger or what name I gave the trigger?

Comment: Yes you can. This will show you the trigger if you search for the trigger itself.
`SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS 
WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA='yourSchema' AND TRIGGER_NAME='yourTriggername'`

Or this will show you the triggers which are on a defined table:

`SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS 
WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA='yourSchema' AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='yourTable'`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (name,date) values(?,CURDATE())";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($name));

        $q = $pdo->prepare( '
             update orders
             set orderId = id
             where id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'
        );
        $q->execute();          

        Database::disconnect();
    }
```

should work now

Comment: Care to explain what this is supposed to achieve?

Comment: Well, I have IDs which reset every mounth, so on june I have an ID 1 and on april I have always an ID 1. But I need also IDs which are unique.

Comment: I tried to update my code exactly like you wrote here, but in my database the orderID stays empty

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO orders (name,date,orderID) values(?,CURDATE(),@last_id_in_table1 )
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot use max (id), because I have sometimes the same IDs. The newest ID is not always the highest

Comment: This won't work always. If he deletes the latest inserted id (e.g. 5) `MAX(id)`will return 4 (which means 4+1 = 5). But the next autoid will be 6 as 5 was already used.

Comment: Never use `MAX(id)` when you want to get the *latest* id - the two aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create another column in your database to hold this value, it's just duplicated data and will only serve to take up unnecessary space.

When you are retrieving data you can use `CONCAT(id, date) AS orderid` to get the concatenated value.

For example, to get all orderids for John:

```
SELECT CONCAT(id,date) AS orderid from `orders` WHERE `name`="John"
```

Comment: @Jarla Use the `select` wherever you need to get the data back out of your database. You don't mention in your question what you do with the data once it's in your database so I can't be more specific.