# How can I insert a value into the last database entry?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a little tricky code, maybe you have a better solution:

What I want to do is, take the "id" of the last inserted entry from the database (1), then put two zeros infront of it (001), take the current "date" and format it (1506) and insert all together (1506001) again into the same row in my database into "orderID".

```
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1';
        foreach ($pdo->query($sql1) as $row) {

          $dateID = date("ym", strtotime($row['date'])); 
          $id = sprintf("%03d", $row['id']);
          $orderID = $dateID.$id;

          $sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (orderID) values('$orderID') ";
          $q2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
          $q2->execute();

          Database::disconnect();
        }
```

For example:

```
id  date   name    orderID
==========================
1   1505   John    1505001
2   1505   Jane    1505002
1   1506   Mad     1506001
2   1506   Fred    1506002
```

What happens now is, that a new row is created. The value of "oderID" is not stored into the same row and I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: Change your INSERT to a UPDATE! But like in your duplicate question, why bother you have all that information already, just do the concatenation from id and date when you show that data on screens or reports or invoices etc.

Comment: The other commentators are mistaken. There's no point storing derived data

Comment: Pretty much an exact duplicate of [How can I create a value from two other values in the same table in my SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916742/how-can-i-create-a-value-from-two-other-values-in-the-same-table-in-my-sql)

Comment: you mean you want to correct the row where orderid was not generated...

Comment: I changed it exactly like you said, but then nothing is stored into "orderID"

Comment: "orderID" should be automatically created from "id" and "date"

Comment: no this is not a copy, I just need help for a specific point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume after the first INSERT the field orderID is NULL.
You could therefore run a query that updates ALL records `WHERE orderID IS NULL`. No need to pull any values into PHP, MySQL's lpad(), date_format() and concat functions should do the trick.

[sscce](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo);

/* insert new orders */
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (`name`, `date`) VALUES (:name, Now())');
$stmt->bindParam('name', $name);
foreach( array('John', 'Jane', 'Matt', 'Fred') as $name ) {
    $stmt->execute();
}

/* 'fix' orderIDs */
$pdo->exec("
    UPDATE
        soFoo
    SET
        orderID = concat(
            date_format(`date`, '%y%m'),
            lpad(`id`, 3, '0')
        )
    WHERE
        orderID IS NULL
");


/* print result */
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM soFoo', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $r ) {
    echo join(', ', $r), "\r\n";
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            `id` int auto_increment,
            `date` Date,
            `name` varchar(32),
            `orderID` varchar(32),
            primary key(id)
        )'
    );
}
```

prints (today):

```
1, 2015-06-19, John, 1506001
2, 2015-06-19, Jane, 1506002
3, 2015-06-19, Matt, 1506003
4, 2015-06-19, Fred, 1506004
```

...but that still leaves the question what you will do once there are a thousand orders in that table.

Comment: sounds nice, how do I do this exactly?

Comment: you mean this: `$sql2 = "UPDATE orders (orderID) values('$orderID') WHERE orderID IS NULL ";`

Comment: wait a minute, SSCCE coming

Comment: Hello, I inserted my code as an example above. The update will be difficult for me. You inserted for example many names at once. But I have only one name per order. But, thank you, I will try to work with your code

Comment: `But I have only one name per order` - makes no difference. The forloop is only there to demonstrate that the UPDATE statements works no matter how many "un-treated" records there are. There more pressing question is what you will do once there a thousand records in that table. I guess you actually had something in mind that keeps track of the orders per month and then start with 001 again the next month?

Comment: `$sql2 = "UPDATE orders SET orderID = '$orderID' WHERE orderID IS NULL";`This should be work actually, I took from your code, but somehow it doesn't

Comment: No, my idea is not working if you have to pull values back to php as you obviously did -> `orderID = '$orderID'`

Comment: for example this works: `UPDATE orders SET orderID = 12;`. Every entry with 0 is now 12. But this is not working: `UPDATE orders SET orderID = 12 WHERE orderID IS NULL;`Here the 0 stays zero. So there must be a problem with `WHERE orderID IS NULL`

Comment: Then there's alreay something "in" that field. Maybe an empty string? An empty string is NOT NULL.

Comment: In my database I have Type INT, length:11, Standard: none. I tried to change the standard to ZERO but I get an ERROR: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'orderID'

Comment: oh, an INT. You need just one distinct value that marks untreated records. In this case `0`will do instead of NULL. But since there's still the "per month issue" you probably need some other solution anyway.

Comment: Oh!! NOW it works ;D This was my problem: I tried to change the STANDARD to NULL. But I needed to make a check mark to NULL. Now it works and it also works with `orderID = '$orderID'. Thank you very much for all you patience. Appreciate this :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`:

```
    $sql2 = "UPDATE `orders` SET `orderID` = '$orderID' 
    WHERE 
        `id` = {$row['id']} 
    AND `date` ='{$row['date']}'
    AND `name` = '{$row['name']}' 
    AND `orderID` ='{$row['orderID']}'
    AND `orderID` != '$orderID'";
```

Comment: I cannot use "WHERE id", because I have more than one id with the same value

Comment: Then it is not `id`! OK, see my edited answer - I hope that id, date and name will be sufficient to find this unique record.

Comment: Then you have made a fundermental mistake in your database design

Comment: well yes, the real id is orderID

Comment: But what happens if John makes 2 orders on the same day??? Fundemental database design error. When things get this difficult to do review your database design.

Comment: It is no problem on the same day. Johns first order: 1505001, Johns second order one minute later: 1505002

Comment: isnt there a code like UPDATE orders WHERE "get last inserted entry"

Comment: You can delete the last record and insert afterwards: $sql1 = 'DELETE FROM orders ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1';

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

1. Use **mysql_insert_id()** to get last inserted id
2. Create your new value for field orderID
3. Update your table for id you have got through **mysql_insert_id()**

Comment: Make sure your id field is auto incremented.

Comment: And If you have multiple query execution simultaneously lock your table before running mysql_insert_id()